# check for specific textboxes to not be null

Tags: vb.net, textbox, null

I know the code below can be used for checking null textboxes.

```
Dim emptyTextBoxes =
From txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
Where txt.Text.Length = 0
Select txt.Name
If emptyTextBoxes.Any Then
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please fill following textboxes: {0}",
                String.Join(",", emptyTextBoxes)))
End If
```

What if I want to check only specific texboxes. For example I have 10 textboxes and I only want 6 of them to be checked if they are null or not

Comment: What is unique about the 6 you want to check? I mean compared with the other 4?

Comment: the other four can get null and sometimes user doesn't want to fill them

Comment: You can name them similarly, then filter with `Where` i.e. `Where txt.Name.StartsWith("prefix")`